# Specific pattern search with MySQL and PHP - How shoud be done?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, pattern-matching

I am new in MySQL and PHP, so I don't really know how to do this. I read a lot about pattern matching, but I don't know how to solve my problem with all I read.

I have a database with a specific code in Column no. 1, and meaning of that code in Column no. 2. Here is an example:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Code          | Meaning   |
+---------------+-----------+
| A5-B10-C11-D3 | object 1  | 
| A5-B10-C50-D8 | object 2  |
| A6-B10-C11-D7 | object 3  | 
| A2-B10-C11-D9 | object 4  |
| A5-B19-C11-D7 | object 5  | 
| A1-B10-C50-D8 | object 6  |
+---------------+-----------+
```

What I want to make is Search with options to search the first column by choosing next patterns:

- Beginning with (X...) - a user will type A5 and it will get Objects 1, 2 & 5
- Ending with (..X) - a user will type D7 and it will get Objects 3 & 5
- Contains in succession (X Y) - a user will type A5 B10 and it will get Objects 1 & 2
- Contains in any order (X Y) but Y always follows X - a user will type B10 C11 and it will get Objects 1,3 & 4, or B10 D8 and it will get Objects 2 & 6
- Contains both, but without order - Y can come before or after X - the user will type D7 A5 and it will get Object 5.

That is enough for the beginning. Of course, this codes would be even more complicated  - for example, B10-B10-A1-D15-C8, but the search options would cover all patterns.

Thank you in advance. If I am not clear what I want, please tell me so I can explain further or give more examples.

ADDITION:

The solution of every code part (A5, B10, etc.) in the separate row doesn't work for me.

This would have the more practical solution in my case:

```
 +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 | 1st place | 2nd place | 3rd place | 4th place | Meaning   |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 | A5        | B10       | C11       | D3        | object 1  | 
 | A5        | B10       | C50       | D8        | object 2  |
 | A6        | B10       | C11       | D7        | object 3  | 
 | A2        | B10       | C11       | D9        | object 4  |
 | A5        | B19       | C11       | D7        | object 5  | 
 | A1        | B10       | C50       | D8        | object 6  |
 +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

So for example code A5-B10-C11-D3 would have meaning od Object 1.

So, my search will allow users to search by next methods and get subsequent results:

- No order: B10 - Result: Objects 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
- Begin with: B10 - Result: none.
- End with: B10 - Result: none.
- No order: A5-B10 (or A5 B10, without dash) - Result: Objects 1, 2
- Begin with: A5-B10 (or A5 B10, without dash) - Result: Objects 1, 2
- End with: A5-B10 (or A5 B10, without dash) - Result: none.
- Contain both (order Y after X, w/o or w/ other characters between) B10-C11 (or B10 C11, without dash) - Result: Object 1, 2, 4.
- etc.

Could something like that could be done?

Comment: a simple LIKE %value% will do it in your mysql-statement

Comment: or `LIKE 'value%'`... But might want to read up on "Database normalization".

Comment: If your database is large, most of these pattern searches will be very slow. MySQL can only use an index to match the beginning of the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` for most of these pattern matches.

- Beginning with: `WHERE code LIKE 'A5-%'`
- Ending with: `WHERE code LIKE '%-D7'`
- Contains in succession: `WHERE code LIKE '%A5-B10-%`
- Contains in order: `WHERE code LIKE '%B10-%C11%'`
- Contains in either order: This can't be done with a single pattern, use `OR`: `WHERE code LIKE '%D7-%A5%' OR code LIKE '%A5-%D7%'`

Except for "beginning with", these will be inefficient since they can't make use of indexes. If there's meaningful structure to your codes, it might be better to split them into separate columns, which you can search explicitly.

Another option is to normalize your data so each part is in a separate row of another table, with a foreign key to the meaning.

`Codes`:

```
Part_Num    Code    Meaning_ID
1           A5      1
2           B10     1
3           C11     1
4           D3      1
1           A5      2
2           B10     2
3           C50     2
4           D8      2
```

`Meanings`:

```
ID  Meaning
1   object 1
2   object 2
```

You can then use tests like:

```
WHERE Part_Num = 1 AND Code = 'A5'
WHERE Part_Num = 4 AND Code = 'D7'
```

For getting codes in succession:

```
SELECT a.Meaning_ID
FROM Codes AS a
JOIN Codes AS b ON a.Meaning_ID = b.Meaning_ID AND a.Part_Num = b.Part_Num - 1
WHERE a.Code = 'A5' AND b.Code = 'B10';
```

For codes in order, but not succession:

```
SELECT a.Meaning_ID
FROM Codes AS a
JOIN Codes AS b ON a.Meaning_ID = b.Meaning_ID AND a.Part_Num < b.Part_Num
WHERE a.Code = 'B10' AND b.Code = 'C11';
```

For codes in any order:

```
SELECT Meaning_ID
FROM Codes
WHERE Code IN ('D7', 'A5')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Using your new table where you've split the code into separate columns of the row, you can do the last query with:

```
WHERE 'D7' IN (1stPlace, 2ndPlace, 3rdPlace, 4thPlace) AND 'A5' IN (1stPlace, 2ndPlace, 3rdPlace, 4thPlace)
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch.  Because of the way MySQL builds its index, would there be a better solution?  Maybe a separate table that pre-bakes the desired results which can be created and updated dynamically?

Comment: Thank you for this advice. Yes, there is a meaningful structure of my code - actually every of this code parts (A5, B10, etc.) is actually signs of language, which together create words, and the "Objects" are words (translations).
So, you think that would be better to put every sign in the separate column? How then would this search function, I mean, what would be the coding approach? And, because I have codes with different numbers of code parts, I will in some cases have empty cells of some words. What should I use to fill this empty cells?

Comment: It's hard to give good advice without really understanding the subject matter, but they'd be something like `WHERE code1 = 'A5'`, `WHERE code4 = 'D7'`, etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to redesign the table to make this all easier.

Comment: I'm not going to write your whole application for you. I think I've provided enough information that you should be able to generalize to your needs.

Comment: I didn't want that anyway, I just want a hint for one of these last examples I added, so I can understand the principle. Thank you again, I will try to find a solution on my own with all this useful help you provided.

Comment: I've added that to my answer.